# How to read external txt into SAS options?

Tags: sas

I have the following authentication lines hard coded :

```
 1. libname xxx odbc user=userName password=passWord dsn=myDsn
    schema=mySchema;

 2. proc sql;  connect to xxx(dsn=myDsn user=userName password=passWord
    );
```

I want to keep the `userName` and `passWord` in an external `.txt` files and refer to them in the code . So that I do not keep them hard coded as it is right now . How can I do this ?

**EDIT:** My main objective is to be able to change/maintain my passwords more easily, NOT to improve security.

Comment: Are you doing this for higher security, or to be able to change them more easily?

Comment: Both, however the primary reason is to be able to change them more easily

Comment: I ask because there are security options (like PWENCODE) that don't exactly make it easier to change, but do make it more secure.  Moving it to a text file doesn't really make it more secure, but does make it easier to change.

Comment: Ok, well . My number one concern is to be able to change userName and Password more easily. Security is not a concern if it make the process more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data-step to read in a file containing password information, see the following for an example. This code assumes the password file is formatted as `username|password` i.e. pipe delimited and only containing one line.

```
filename pw ""; /*<insert name of pw file here>*/

data _NULL_;
  infile pw dlm='|'; /* Change dlm if not pipe */
  input 
  uname : $50.
  pw : $50.;
  call symputx('uname',uname);
  call symputx('pw',pw);
run;

libname xxx odbc user=&uname. password=&pw. dsn=myDsn schema=mySchema;

proc sql;  
  connect to xxx(dsn=myDsn user=&uname. password=&pw.);
```

If you are working on a metadata server you can use authentication domains to hold password information instead.

In that case you would alter your password in the metadata and then refer to it in code using the `authdomain=` option, which would return the password to SAS without it being displayed.

e.g.

```
libname xxx odbc authdomain=MY_ODBC_AUTHDOMAIN dsn=myDsn schema=mySchema;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're primarily concerned with ease of changing (or perhaps sharing the file among several users), you can use a %include file and/or a macro stored in your MAUTOCALL library to connect.  IE

(text file)

```
%let con_str=dsn=myDsn user=userName password=passWord;
```

(SAS code)

```
proc sql;  
  connect to xxx(&con_str.);
```

If you put that in a macro, and compiled it without the SOURCE option, you could hide the values from whomever was running it.

You also can use `PROC PWENCODE` to encode the password, and then use the encoded password in your program.  From [the documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002598191.htm):

```
filename pwfile "external-file";

proc pwencode in='mypass1' out=pwfile;
run;
```

then

```
filename pwfile 'external-filename';
options symbolgen;

data _null_;
   infile pwfile obs=1 length=l; 
   input @;
   input @1 line $varying1024. l; 
   call symput('dbpass',substr(line,1,l)); 
run;
libname x odbc dsn=SQLServer user=testuser password="&dbpass";
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the first method is easier for me . I tried `libname passLib 'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Authentication' ;
options sasautos=(sasautos passLib) ; 

proc sql;  
connect to odbc(&con_str.);` 
 But got `ERROR: Invalid option name &.`

Comment: Hmmm.  You may have to store the user/password separately, then, more like mjsqu shows.  Or, alternately, contain the entire text of the connection in the macro and/or macro variable (ie, everyting including `connect to... ;`)

Comment: @Joe your solution works great., and I am trying to do this on a remote server but gives me an error.. physical files does not exist. 
I have the filename path changed to the location on the remote server .. however it doesnot take it. any tips on this? i wrote the filename statement as
'code' filename clip "/home/user/clipboard.txt" and ran it a rsubmit.

Comment: @user3658367 You should ask a new question and put the full code in the question, plus make sure you're clear on where the file is (physically on local, remote, or network drive accessible by one/both?).